# Cordova Appframework rangeslider, can't move slider

Tags: jquery, cordova, slider, appframework

I got a problem driving me nots.

I'm using Appframework 3.0 with Cordova, and trying to make some settings for my App.

```
<div id="slider">
        <form action="xxxxx.xxx" method="get">
        Points:
        <input type="range" name="minrange" min="20" max="100" step="1" value="45">
            </br>
        <input type="range" name="maxrange" min="20" max="100" step="1" value="55">
            <input type="button">
        </form>
</div>
```

The code above shows both sliders in my App, but I can't move them. Sliders doesn't seems to be a part of AppFramework. So can anyone tell me why I can't move sliders?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I sorted out.

I still don't know why it doesn't work in a view (Appframework), but if I put a panel (Appframework) inside the view, it works like charm.

Hope this answer can help someone else.